# How to pass an unknown number of values as a key in key value pairs? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, key-value

Sorry for the confusing title. Basically, I have an object which has a heap of key-value-pairs. For instance:

```
this[1,2] = "some output";
```

If I knew the key was going to be made of two values I could go like:

```
let someValue = 1;
let someOtherValue = 2;
console.log(this[someValue,someOtherValue]);
//Outputs "some output"
```

However, if my key was made up of some number of values "n" and the only way I know this is from some other variable:

```
var numberOfKeys = n;
```

How do I access, say, the first value (0,0,0,0...) with code?
Thanks in advance I hope you can understand the question.

**Edit:**
Thanks everyone, I understand now. Originally I didn't think the idea of passing in multiple values as the key would work, but when I tried it in JSfiddle it did seem to. This was just the illusion given by what everyone has pointed out about how the comma operator just takes the last value. I understand now and will just use a normal multidimensional array to the same effect. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: `this[1,2] = "some output";` I don't get it, what's the purpose of the comma operator there? (all but the last expression in the comma-separated list will be ignored) If you were trying to assign one value to two indicies of an array, that's not how you do it

Comment: Also dont get it, but i am thinking that that the Key to this Map is a tuple?

Comment: Probably doesn't realize that `(1,2) === 2`

Comment: _"If I knew the key was going to be made of two values"_ there's no such thing as a key that's a tuple in JavaScript. `this[someValue,someOtherValue]` is equivalent to `this[someOtherValue]`, since the comma operator simply discards the return value of the left hand operand and returns the value of the right hand operand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` to map over the keys you want to access:

```js
// Your object
const object = {
  firstKey: 'first value',
  secondKey: 'second value',
  thirdKey: 'third value',
};

// Your n number of keys
const keys = ['firstKey', 'thirdKey'];

// Map over the keys you want to get and return values
const result = keys.map(key => object[key]);

// Do something with the values
console.log(result.join(' and '));
```